# Why does my Vue Spa not work in mobile offline mode?

Tags: vuejs2, progressive-web-apps, offline-mode

i run into a (at least for me) strange issue with vue.

I created an SPA without any remote content. Just a .html file, some css and vue to "jump" between content divs.

The SPA was created for mobile devices.

When i visit the page with internet connection everything works fine.

Now is "add the page to homescreen".

When i open the "app" (homescreen page) without internet connection the click event does no longer work.

When i open the "app" with internet connection, again everything does work as expected.

Does anyone have a clue what's wrong in here?

UPDATE:
The issue seems to appear only on tablet. I have tried on a smartphone and the app does work even in offline Mode.

Maybe relevant:
Tablet: Nexus 7
OS: Android 6.0.1
Browser: Chrome 75.0.3770.67

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED 
The issue was, that the JS Code was not stored when adding the Page to the Homescreen. I have added a service worker to cache the assets. Now everything works like a charme :)